# Exercise 5.2.2. - Analysis I (Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, real-numbers

I tried to prove the statement in the exercise 5.2.2 that says:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Show that if $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ are eventually $\varepsilon$-close, then $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded if and only if $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded.

I think that one path in order to prove this, is prove the following statement:

***Proposition.*** Let $\varepsilon > 0$. If $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ are eventually $\varepsilon$-close and $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded, then $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded.

*Proof*. Let  $\varepsilon > 0$. Assume that $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ are eventually $\varepsilon$-close and $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded. Then we have $(a_n)_{n = N}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n = N}^{\infty}$ are $\varepsilon$-close, where $N \geq 1$; furthermore $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by some $M \geq 0$.

In the case of $N = 1$, we have $(a_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ and $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ are $\varepsilon$-close. Let $i \geq 1$, then $|a_i - b_i| \leq \varepsilon$ and $|a_i| \leq M$, and considering that $|b_i| = |b_i - a_i + a_i| \leq |b_i - a_i| + |a_i|$, we have $|b_i| \leq M + \varepsilon$. We can conclude $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by $M + \varepsilon$ and hence it is bounded.

In the case of $N \neq 1$, we have $N - 1 \geq 1$. We know $b_1, \dots, b_{N-1}$ is bounded (by Lemma 5.1.14). Let $i \geq N$, we have $|a_i| \leq M$ and $|a_i - b_i| \leq \varepsilon$, and considering $|b_i| \leq |a_i - b_i| + |a_i|$, we have $|b_i| \leq M + \varepsilon$; we can conclude $(b_n)_{n = N}^{\infty}$ is bounded by $M + \varepsilon$. Knowing $b_1, \dots, b_{N-1}$ is bounded by some $T \geq 0$, we have  $|b_j| \leq T$ for each $1 \leq j \leq N - 1$. Let $i \geq 1$. In the case of $i \leq N - 1$, we have $|b_i| \leq T \leq M + T + \varepsilon$. In the case of $i > N - 1$, we have $i \geq N$, therefore $|b_i| \leq M + \varepsilon \leq M + T + \varepsilon$. We can conclude $(b_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is bounded by $M + T + \varepsilon$ and hence it is bounded. This completes the proof.

Any suggestion will be valuable.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks! @PrincessEev